# Работа с бд в laravel при помощи sql кода

Tags: php, laravel

Привет.

Сейчас занимаюсь переносом одного проекта на laravel. Непонятно как работать с бд, очень все сложно и запутанно, нужно использовать какие-то встроенные в laravel классы и работать с каждой таблицей отдельно. Но для меня это дико не удобно, во-первых зачем изучать методы этой ORM когда можно писать сами SQL запросы? Как это можно делать в laravel, т.е. писать sql запросы и выполнять их, что-то наподобии встроенного в php класса PDO?

P.S. В Opencart реализована очень удобная модель работы с бд, есть функции которые выполняет нужные sql запросы и возвращают ответ, все понятно и удобно.

Answer (score 0):

См. [Laravel:Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries)

Пример:

```
// select
$users = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', [1]);
$users = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]); // named binding

// insert
DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);

// update
$affected = DB::update('update users set votes = 100 where name = ?', ['John']);

// delete
$deleted = DB::delete('delete from users');
```